# redis-cli how to AUTH using password and issue a command?

Tags: redis

When no password is set, we can issue for instance;

```
>> redis-cli keys *
```

or

```
>> redis-cli config set requirepass "aaaaaa"
```

However, after we have have issued the latter, the first no longer works and results in:

```
>> redis-cli keys *
  (error) NOAUTH Authentication required.
```

We need to authenticate. Sure.

```
>> redis-cli AUTH aaaaaa
   OK
>> redis-cli keys *
   (error) NOAUTH Authentication required.
```

How do we authenticate and then able to execute a command?

Is this not possible? Heredocs only?

I've tried:

```
>> redis-cli AUTH aaaaaa && config set requirepass "aaaaaa"
```

But did not work. Also semicolon after aaaaaa. Not work.

How?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `AUTH` commands only last for the duration of the tcp connection. Each new invocation of `redis-cli` creates a new connection, thus you have to authenticate at each invocation.

It is possible to execute several redis commands on one invocation of `redis-cli`: they must be separated by `\n`

Thus this would work:

```
echo -e 'AUTH aaaaaa\nkeys *' | redis-cli
```

Note: The other answer also provides a way to pass arguments separated by `\n` to `redis-cli`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I tried to redis-cli 'AUTH aaaaaa\nkeys *' but did not work last time. Will try again. Albeit, I was able to get it to work with EOF below.

Comment: @mmm The problem with `redis-cli 'AUTH aaaaaa\nkeys *'` is that the shell doesn't understand that `\n`means  a new line. When you do that you literally send the characters \ then n. Also please accept the answer if it solved your issue

Answer (score 10):

You can pass the -a argument for authenticating the redis-cli command like this:

```
redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -a mypassword keys *
```

Comment: this is correct, but I was looking for a way to load it through a config file, because it's considered unsafe to do in the terminal through the `-a` flag ... guess there is no way to do that...?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
redis-cli <<- 'EOF'
        AUTH aaaaaa
        config set requirepass aaaaaa
EOF
```